# Mental malingerer in a single word

Tags: single-word-requests

What can you call a malingerer who specifically says he has a severe mental illness (OCD, serious depression, bipolar, autism, neuro-divergency ADHD, or other mental disorder)?

In my idea, "Malingerer" goes best with minor physical ailments, pain, toothache and the like, while I am looking for a single word for somebody who claims to have (multiple) severe mental disorders.

I am not saying that these illnesses don't exist (I did once work in a psychiatric hospital), but the person claiming to have them has no real idea how serious these conditions really would be if he had been diagnosed with even one of them.

Research done:

I did try to find it on Wikipedia, found "fictitious disorder" (2 words),  did google it and was refered to the same.

"Mental malingerer" is something I made up myself (2 words).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141711/discussion-on-question-by-willemien-mental-malingerer-in-a-single-word).

Comment: Malingering is the feigning of any disorder in order to shirk. The UCMJ defines it as "feign[ing] illness, physical disablement, mental lapse, or derangement." So you don't need or want a new word.

Comment: I was thinking _Munchausen Syndrome_ but that's different.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to take the Latin *mentis* meaning "of the mind" or *mens* meaning "mind", or "psycho" from the Greek *psykho* meaning "mental" and make a word like *psychomalingerer* or *malingermenser* (the former preferred I think).

Comment: Hello, Robert. If you check back, you can see that  'D-I-Y-isms' (candidate words), and hence the encouragement to devise them, are expressly off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Okay, thank you.